# How to stop visual studio 2013 to change .sln version

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

i have a **C#** project that i work on using visual studion 2013, the project was created with visual studio **2010**, and the entire project is located on a local server and i am using Team Explorer to access it.

the problem is that if i make changes to the project and check-in the Solution (.sln) to the server, and my co workers, that use visual studio 2010, try to open the solution they get an error that the solution was created with a newer version of visual studio.

is there any way to force visual studio 2013 to **not** change the version number in the solution file? so even though i make changes to the solution the version will not change?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026239/how-can-i-stop-visual-studio-automatically-upgrading-projects ?

Comment: Or don't check in the solution file.

Comment: Basically you can't, all developers working on a given project/solution have to use the same version of VS. You can have 2 copies of all the projects/solution files, but the any changes you make like adding/removing/moving files will only reflect in the version of VS you make the change in.

Comment: As lc & Ben have said, do not check in the soln file, or atleast the line(s) where it changes the VS version in the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the help guys, i just ended up creating a copy of the solution file so i'll have 2 .sln files, one for each version.
not the best solution i hoped for but it'll have to do.
thanks.